# show that for any complex number $\lambda$ such that $ |\lambda | < 1$ there exists a non-zero $x$ in $H$ such that $A^{\dagger}x = \lambda x$

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space, and $A$ a non-surjective isometric linear operator on $H$, $e_0 \in H$ a unit vector that is orthogonal to the range of $A$, $e_n = A^ne_0$  and $A^{\dagger}$ denotes the adjoint.

**Question :** show that for any complex number $\lambda$ such that $ |\lambda | < 1$ there exists a non-zero $x$ in $H$ such that $A^{\dagger}x = \lambda x$

I have shown the following, they might be useful :

- $\{e_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ is an orthonormal set
- $A^{\dagger}e_0 = 0$
- $A^{\dagger}e_n = e_{n-1}, \,\,\, \forall n \geq 1$

Comment: Write down the recurrence for the coefficients of $x$.  Solve it.  Easy.

Comment: @GEdgar I did that but kind of got a contradiction, I ended up with the following $\lambda \alpha_i = \alpha_{i+1}$ for $i \leq n-1$, however $\lambda \alpha_n$ must be $0$, I got lost at this point. (the $\alpha$'s are the coefficients here)

Comment: Consider the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^ne_n$. Its sum $y$ (prove that it has one using that $|\lambda|<1$) will satisfy $A^\dagger y = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda^n e_{n-1}=\lambda\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^ne_n=\lambda y$.